# How to compare two different array and remove object from one Array based on Key?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I have two Array Objects and I want to compare them and remove if value matches from both array.

```
Arr1 = [
        {id: "one", name: "one", status: "Active"}, 
        {id: "two", name: "two", status: "Active"}, 
        {id: "three", name: "three", status: "Active"}
      ]

Arr2 = [
        {pid: "one", order: 1}, 
        {pid: "two", order: 2}
      ]
```

Now I want if `id === pid` then it should not return.

```
finalArr = [
            {id: "three", name: "three", status: "Active"}
           ]
```

I tried Below Solution but somehow it is not working and it returns Empty Array.

```
finalArr  = Arr1.filter((a) => {
    Arr2.some((b) => {
        a['id'] === b['pid'];        
    });
});
```

Please do let me know if you need more information. I hope I am able to convey my concern.4

Thanks!

Comment: `some` should return something. Using a bracket (`{`) forces you to add a `return`, otherwise `void 0` (`undefined`) is implicitly returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged [lodash](/questions/tagged/lodash), you can consider using the [`_.differenceWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#differenceWith) method, which allows you to provide a comparator function to specify what property you should take the difference by. However, if you're not already using lodash, then a vanilla approach is preferable.

```js
const arr1 = [{id: "one", name: "one", status: "Active"},  {id: "two", name: "two", status: "Active"}, {id: "three", name: "three", status: "Active"}];
const arr2 = [{pid: "one", order: 1}, {pid: "two", order: 2}];
const res = _.differenceWith(arr1, arr2, ({id}, {pid}) => id === pid);

console.log(res); // [{ "id": "three", "name": "three", "status": "Active" }]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are in almost right direction, you have to place `!` condition before `some` so it will not bring the matched array. Here is a one liner:

```js
var Arr1 = [ {id: "one", name: "one", status: "Active"},  {id: "two", name: "two", status: "Active"},  {id: "three", name: "three", status: "Active"} ];

var Arr2 = [{pid: "one", order: 1},  {pid: "two", order: 2} ];

var result = Arr1.filter(k=>!Arr2.some(p=>p.pid==k.id));

console.log(result);
```

With your solution:

```js
var Arr1 = [ {id: "one", name: "one", status: "Active"},  {id: "two", name: "two", status: "Active"},  {id: "three", name: "three", status: "Active"} ];

var Arr2 = [{pid: "one", order: 1},  {pid: "two", order: 2} ];

var finalArr = Arr1.filter((a) => {
    return !Arr2.some((b) => {
        return a['id'] === b['pid'];        
    });
});

console.log(finalArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const arr2Pid = Arr2.map((value) => value.pid); // getting the pid from array 2
console.log(Arr1.filter((value) => arr2Pid.indexOf(value.id) < 0 )) // filtering the Arr1 if pid != id of Arr1
```

Comment: If you make `arr2Pid` a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), you can make this O(n+m) rather than O(nm) as you can use `.has()` instead of `.indexOf()`

Comment: Correct, that is an area where we can improve the performance.